# Phone USB hotplug opens odd directory in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, android

When plugging in my Galaxy Nexus 5 into my computer, explorer tries to open to %HOME%/Desktop/page04/

The phone shows just as a USB hub with a MTP device and the Android Debug Bridge on it (no HID emulation or anything else that is similar).
I've checked the windows autoplay settings and it is set to take no action.

Anyone know why this might be happening and how I can prevent it?

Edit: Apparently it also happens on some other events too as it's still randomly happening even though my phone is unplugged, though phone hotplug is a guaranteed trigger event.